# React does not recognize the `isDisabled` prop on a DOM element on img element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

After I updated my React/Next.js App, I get this error:

React does not recognize the `isDisabled` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `isdisabled` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

[image]

This is how I use that img:

```
<img src={user?.photoURL ? user?.photoURL : "https://xxxxxxx"} alt="avatar" className="w-8 h-8 rounded-full border-2 border-violet-600 cursor-pointer" />
```

If I remove that `<img>` and replace it with a, let's say `<span>` the error is gone.

Comment: Could you add the full component please?

Comment: Is there `isDisabled` anywhere in that component?

Comment: Please provide entire component to look into

Comment: The entire component is too big to add it here. I also tried using <Avatar src=""> or the Next Image component and the error is still there. If I replace the img with anything else, it works fine. This only happens on development. On production there isn't any error

Comment: There is no "isDisable" attribute in your code, so as the error says, I suppose you are passing an attribute/prop isDisabled from the parent to your component and it is automatically inherited on your images

Answer (score -4):

React doesn't support isDisabled prop, try using **disabled** prop just like this:

```
<img disabled={true} src={user?.photoURL ? user?.photoURL : "https://xxxxxxx"} alt="avatar" className="w-8 h-8 rounded-full border-2 border-violet-600 cursor-pointer" />
```

Comment: There is no disabled attribute for images

Comment: Off topic, he don't want to have a isDisabled attribute on image but to understand why this error occurs while he hasn't set this attribute.